# Finding extrema of $f(x,y) = sin(xy)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I did calculate $f_{xy}(x,y)$ and $f_{yx}(x,y)$ and equating them gives the expression

$$\tan(xy)=-\frac{xy}{2}$$

and equating $f_x(x,y)=0$ and $f_y(x,y)=0$ gives $$xy=(2m+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$$

These are the expressions I got:

$$f_x(x,y) = y\cos(xy)$$

$$f_y(x,y) = x\cos(xy)$$

$$f_{xx}(x,y) = -y^2\sin(xy)$$

$$f_{yy}(x,y) = -x^2\sin(xy)$$

$$f_{xy}(x,y) = -2y\sin(xy)-xy^2\cos(xy)$$

$$f_{yy}(x,y) = -2x\sin(xy)-x^2y\cos(xy)$$

How do I move from here?

Comment: I think your set up is good. In fact, there are infinitely many solutions to produce the extremas (being 1 or -1). And that happens if the product of $x$ and $y$ turn out to be a $\pi$ multiple of $\pi/2$ This is what you came up with. What else would be required at this point?

Comment: You're done. Along the hyperbolas defined by $xy = (2m+1) \pi/2$ (for $m \in \mathbb Z$), the sine is either +1 or -1 (depending on $m$ even or odd), and these are curves of maxima/minima (sort of like how the long lines of the tops of ocean waves are straight lines all points of which are maxima (assuming perfect waves).

Comment: Shoot. I thought too much about this. Thank you both for the explanation.

Comment: The plural of extremum is extrema (sometimes extremums).

Answer (score 6):

You do not need the tools of calculus here, as we have a pretty good idea about how the $\sin$ function looks like. Also, I am not sure why you need cross partial derivatives.

$\sin(xy)$ has maximum value of $1$ at every $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ $xy = \pi/2 + 2n\pi$. Then, whenever you have $y=\pi\frac{1+4n}{2x}$, you will have a maximum.

Comment: Thank you. I was working on multivariable calculus and ended up finding partials for the problem unnecessarily.